# The bottom of the Favorite button is cut off

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, display, bookmarks

I just noticed that the bottom of the circular "favorite this question" button is cut off, both on Mi Yodeya and Mi Yodeya Meta:

[image: Portion of a Mi Yodeya question page, with the bottom of the Favorite button cut off] [image: Portion of a Mi Yodeya Meta question page, with the bottom of the Favorite button cut off]

This issue also applies to the Favorites section of the user profile page:

[image: The Favorites section of a user profile page, with the bottoms of Favorite buttons cut off]

I spot-checked a few different questions and saw this issue on each one. I'm not sure when it started. I'm [not the only user](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29545535#29545535) to experience this. I see this issue in Chrome, both on a Windows desktop and on an Android phone. The comments on this post indicate that the issue applies to varioius browsers on various platforms.

Comment: Replicated on Chrome Windows

Comment: Replicated on Firefox Windows.

Comment: Replicated on Safari Mac.

Comment: Replicated in Firefox and Chromium on Ubuntu. `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0` and `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/49.0.2623.108 Chrome/49.0.2623.108 Safari/537.36`.

Comment: Replicated on Chrome Mac.  I think it's pretty safe to call this one as not being browser- or OS-dependent.

Comment: @Monica it's a good thing it's not p-t season, as I'm tempted to stealth-edit the question to make you all be testifying to something weird and amusing.

Comment: He says, to someone who can stealth-edit his comment.  :-) But I wouldn't, of course.

Comment: Cannot replicate in lynx 2.8.8.

Comment: @msh210 screenshot, please

Comment: @IsaacMoses http://i.stack.imgur.com/MdH7N.png

Comment: @msh210 That's surprisingly good-looking. It looks like the whole favorite button is cut off, though.

Comment: I seems that the number under the star shoud be one line below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be fixed now, it will be live after our next production build.

Comment: Fixed now. Thanks!